# How can I check if a field is greater than a certain number if that field has a $ sign in front?

Tags: bash, awk

Given a file called `employee.txt` in the format (Firstname, Lastname, Salary) with space as the field separator:

```
Foo Bar $1,000
First Last $5,550
Abc Def $3,000
Stack Overflow $6000
Help Please $4700
```

I want to print lines that have its third field greater than $4,000. Desired output:

```
First Last $5,550
Stack Overflow $6000
Help Please $4700
```

I am unsure how to check if a field is greater than 4000, for instance, with the `$` and `,` in it.

I've tried using `sed` to substitute `$` and `,` with blanks then redirect to `awk` but I want the output to contain `$` and `,` like the original.

Is this doable with `awk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{v=$3; gsub(/[$,]/, "", v)} v+0>4000' employee.txt 
First Last $5,550
Stack Overflow $6000
Help Please $4700
```

#### How it works

1. `v=$3`

   Save the third field as variable `v`.
2. `gsub(/[$,]/, "", v)`

   Remove the problematic characters from `v`,
3. `v+0>4000`

   Print lines for which `v` is greater than 4000.

#### Printing a range of values

To print all lines with a value greater than 4000 and less than 5000:

```
$ awk '{v=$3; gsub(/[$,]/, "", v)} v+0>4000 && v+0<5000' employee.txt 
Help Please $4700
```

Comment: Is it also possible to do a range from 4000 to 5000?

Comment: @5areductase Yes, it is.  See updated answer for how to print a range.

Comment: This is performing string comparison! It outputs the same for `v>4000000`.

Comment: @PesaThe OK.  Fixed.  Using v+0>4000 forces a numeric comparison.

Answer (score 1):

For variety, here is a solution using only `bash` (**noticeably** slow for big data compared to `awk` solutions here):

```
while IFS=' ' read -r first last cash; do
    valid_cash=${cash//[$,]/}
    (( valid_cash > 4000 )) && echo "$first $last $cash"
done < employee.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'gensub(/[$,]/,"","g",$NF) > 4000' input_file
```

(g)awk's default action is print